# fscanf() replacing my ADT nodes?

Tags: c

I am writing a function to read from a text file and extract the strings word by word and store them to a binary search tree. The function should ignore all punctuations and discard duplicate words(only adds to the word frequency).

My problem with the code now is that every time "while (fscanf(fp, "%s", line)!=EOF)" runs, my rootWord gets replaced by the newly read word. I cannot figure out how is it possible for fscanf to be able to do this.

```
typedef struct word * wordPtr;
typedef struct position * positionPtr;

typedef struct position
{
    int position;
    positionPtr nextPosition;
} Position;
typedef struct word
{
    char * word;
    unsigned freq;
    positionPtr firstPosition;
    wordPtr leftWord;
    wordPtr rightWord;
} Word;

typedef struct bstWord
{
    wordPtr rootWord;
    unsigned wordCount;
} BSTWord;

int BSTCreate(BSTWord* bst, char* fileName)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char line[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
    int charCount = 0;
    char * token;
    char delimit[] = "\t\r\n\v\f,.-;:\"\' ";    

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", line)!=EOF)
    {
        wordPtr prev = NULL, curr = bst->rootWord;          
        wordPtr newWord;
        positionPtr newPosition;
        int lessThen;
        int status = 1;                         
        token = strtok(line, delimit);          
        charCount = charCount + 1;          

        while(curr!=NULL)
        {
            prev = curr;

            if(strcmp(token, curr->word)<0)
            {
                printf("\nless");
                lessThen = 1;
                curr = curr->leftWord;
                status = 1;
            }
            else if(strcmp(token, curr->word)>0)
            {
                printf("\nmore");
                lessThen = 0;
                curr = curr->rightWord;
                status = 1;
            }
            else if(strcmp(token, curr->word)==0) //If word is already in tree, add freq + update position
            {

                if ( ( newPosition = malloc( sizeof( Position ) ) ) == NULL )
                    return FAILURE;

                newPosition->position = charCount;
                newPosition->nextPosition = NULL;

                positionPtr prevPosition = NULL, currPosition = curr->firstPosition;
                while(currPosition!=NULL)
                {
                    prevPosition = currPosition;
                    currPosition = currPosition->nextPosition;
                }
                prevPosition->nextPosition = newPosition;
                status = 0;
                curr = NULL;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(status == 1)
        {
            if ( ( newWord = malloc( sizeof( Word ) ) ) == NULL )
                return FAILURE;

            if ( ( newPosition = malloc( sizeof( Position ) ) ) == NULL )
                return FAILURE;

            newPosition->position = charCount;

            newWord->word = token;
            newWord->freq = 1;
            newWord->firstPosition = newPosition;
            newWord->leftWord = NULL;
            newWord->rightWord = NULL;

            if(bst->rootWord == NULL)
                bst->rootWord = newWord;
            else
            {
                if(lessThen)
                {   
                    prev->leftWord = newWord;
                }
                else
                {   
                    prev->rightWord = newWord;
                }
            }           
        }
        bst->wordCount++;
    }
    fclose(fp);        
    free(fp);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `strtok()` doesn't allocate a new buffer but returns a pointer into the buffer it was passed?

Comment: I am unaware of that, I will look it up, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newWord->word = token;
```

Every token points to the same memory you allocated at:

```
char line[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
```

You need to allocate additional memory and copy the string there:

```
newword->word = malloc(strlen(token) + 1); 
strcpy(newword->word, token);
```

Comment: Thank you! Did not realized that.